# How to externally register a new user without accessing /user/register?

Tags: 7, users, security

I have a (Drupal 7) site which uses LDAP to authenticate logins according to an Active Directory groups only.

In the Apache config file, the URLs '/user' and '/admin' are both blocked externally. This has been tested and they can't be accessed, neither can '/user/register'.

I have found that some randomly-generated-looking username/email address combinations have appeared on the site. They're created in a blocked state due to the new accounts setting of requiring Administrator approval for a new account. All of their 'last accessed' fields are 'never'.

My question is how the accounts could have been created from an external connection without accessing the URL '/user/register', or any of the other blocked URLs?

Comment: Are you able to post the apache directives that are blocking the url's externally?

Comment: I can: 
# URL Access control to site access

<Location ~ "/(user|admin)">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location>
 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is an internal ip address

Comment: Do you have any URL aliases of /user/register?

Comment: No. The only aliases are for articles.

Comment: Maybe you have a module like Commerce which creates users automatically? I suggest looking in watchdog for entries for the time period right before the users.created. Also, grep your codebase for user_save.